# Liferay 7- Theme does not appear correctly in IE9

Tags: liferay, internet-explorer-9, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

Many of styles are not applied and pages looked weird in IE9, because IE has CSS limitation. The problem is that i can't modify css because it is generated with Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 indeed has [limited support](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix), however, as you can create your own theme, you can change the css that is generated.